# Why variable may not be initialize inside an if

Tags: java, swing

The variable stock at line editRecord shows that the variable may not be initialized

```
        if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("Flower"))
        {

            String filepath = "Stock.txt";
            String name = "Flower";
            String stock;            
            if(add.isSelected())
            {
                stock = String.valueOf(id.getStock(0) + Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
            }
            if(minus.isSelected())
            {
                stock = String.valueOf(id.getStock(0) - Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
            }
            String price = "12.90";
            String amountSold = String.valueOf(id.getItemSold(0));

          editRecord(filepath,name,stock,price,amountSold);

        }
```

Comment: What if both `add.isSelected` and `minus.isSelected` are false?

Comment: Because you have two independent conditional statements in which `stock` is set. It might be that your code is correct, but still Java won't understand that this will cover all cases. If you're sure that if `add` is not selected `minus` will be selected you could just use the second conditional statement as the `else`-clause of your first conditional statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that it can't be initialized in an `if` block, it's that static analysis of the code by the compiler shows that it's possible that it gets to the `editRecord(..., stock, ...)` method call without having been initialized.

E.g.: if neither `add.isSelected()` or `minus.isSelected()` are true, it could be referenced without ever being assigned to, which is bad.

You can solve that by initializing it to null, instead of just declaring it.